# Genymotion Android Emulator

Tags: anonymity

I'm using Tor with a VPN (from privateinternetaccess<sup>TM</sup>), so I thought I was doing pretty good at maintaining anonymity, until I tried to use the Genymotion Android emulator. It links directly to my network and tracks my IP address.

There is a screen to enter http proxy info and port settings (see pic below) - is that advisable?  Where do I get the values to enter - Tor or my VPN?

[image]

Comment: What OS are you running genymotion on? I don't have this issue with genymotion and PIA on lubuntu.

Comment: I'm using Genymotion too, behind ISA proxy, cntlm/tor, and Privoxy.
without GM, works fine, but I don't succed to get GM working behind Privoxy. Have you resolved? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The window you included wants to get a HTTP proxy and its port. I assume you use a recent Tor Browser Bundle. The proxy address and port are `127.0.0.1` and port `9150`.

You probably can get your VPN data from your VPN provider. Maybe there are help pages, support team etc.

I don't know the internals of Genymotion, but it might be the case that it makes requests which circumvent the proxy settings. So first you should test the tool and see if all requests going through the proxy.

Comment: Tor Browser does not come with Privoxy for a good while now.